How to close pages/browser after they are no longer necessary the spider job in scrapy playwright?
I am using this example to load websites in a browser from multiple request.
https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright#:~:text=Use%20this%20carefully%2C%20and%20only%20if%20you%20really%20need%20to%20do%20things%20with%20the%20Page%20object%20in%20the%20callback.%20If%20pages%20are%20not%20properly%20closed%20after%20they%20are%20no%20longer%20necessary%20the%20spider%20job%20could%20get%20stuck%20because%20of%20the%20limit%20set%20by%20the%20PLAYWRIGHT_MAX_PAGES_PER_CONTEXT%20setting.
from playwright.async_api import Page
import scrapy

class AwesomeSpiderWithPage(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "page_spider"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://example.org",
            callback=self.parse_first,
            meta={"playwright": True, "playwright_include_page": True},
            errback=self.errback_close_page,
        )

    def parse_first(self, response):
        page: Page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
        return scrapy.Request(
            url="https://example.com",
            callback=self.parse_second,
            meta={"playwright": True, "playwright_include_page": True, "playwright_page": page},
            errback=self.errback_close_page,
        )

    async def parse_second(self, response):
        page: Page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
        title = await page.title()  # "Example Domain"
        await page.close()
        return {"title": title}

    async def errback_close_page(self, failure):
        page: Page = failure.request.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()

The above example is what I am trying to use. And below example is my code. The problem I am facing is that I am not able to close the browser after the task is complete. And I have not able to fully complete loop from the list after parse second method. Sometime it hits parse second method and sometimes it doesn't. I want to open url in a browser in a sequential order. First it should start from start request->then move to callback parse first -> parse second and so on. The problem is, it moves to parse first and for first two url or third url and it moves to parse second but for last it does not and sometimes it does not move to parse second method for second or third url.
The websites are just a dummy example so that I can test to open the browser and close the browser.
# myplaywrightproject/spiders/example_spider.py

import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from playwright.async_api import Page 
# from scrapy_playwright.page import PageCoroutine

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example_spider"

    start_urls = ["https://www.google.com", "https://www.yahoo.com", "https://www.facebook.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            request = Request(url=url,
                            callback=self.parse_first,
                            meta={
                                "playwright": True,
                                "playwright_include_page": True,
                                "playwright_context": "new",  # Ensures a new context for each request
                            },
                            errback=self.close_context_on_error
                            )
            yield request

    async def parse_first(self, response):
        self.logger.info(f"Loaded page: {response.url}")
        page: Page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
        another_url = ["https://quotes.toscrape.com/"]
        self.logger.info(f"Preparing to load another URL: {another_url}")
        await self.close_page_and_context(page)
        request = Request(url=another_url[0], callback=self.parse_second,
            meta = {
                "playwright": True,
                "playwright_include_page": True,
                "playwright_context": "new"
            },
            errback=self.close_context_on_error
        )
        return request

    async def parse_second(self, response):
        self.logger.info(f"Successfully reached another method with url: {response.url}")
        # # Extract the page title
        page: Page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
        content = response.css("p::text").getall()
        await self.close_page_and_context(page)
        return {"content ==============>": response.url}
        

    custom_settings = {
        "DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS": {
            "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
            "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
        },
        "TWISTED_REACTOR":"twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor",
        "PLAYWRIGHT_LAUNCH_OPTIONS": {
            "headless": False,  # Set to False if you want to see the browser in action
        },
        "LOG_LEVEL": "DEBUG", 
        "PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSER_TYPE": "chromium",
        "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS": 1,
        "PLAYWRIGHT_DEFAULT_NAVIGATION_TIMEOUT": 45 * 1000
    }

    async def close_page_and_context(self, page):
        try:
            if page and not page.is_closed():
                context: BrowserContext = page.context
                await page.close()
                if context and not context.is_closed():
                    await context.close()
                self.logger.info("Closed page and context successfully.")
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(f"Error closing page and context: {e}")

    async def close_context_on_error(self, failure):
        page = failure.request.meta.get("playwright_page")
        if page and not page.is_closed():
            try:
                context: BrowserContext = page.context
                await page.close()
                if context and not context.is_closed():
                    await context.close()
                self.logger.info("Closed context on error.")
            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.error(f"Error closing context on error: {e}")

